# Bookdown figure captions with URL hyperlink

Tags: url, latex, bookdown, caption

I have been trying to use text references to include figure captions in a bookdown document - see code below:

````
(ref:cap) See this [link](http://pkgs.rstudio.com/)

```{r fig.cap = '(ref:cap)'}  
plot(mtcars)
```
````

This works when I compile using the gitbook format but not pdf.  Here is what the log shows me:

```
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 469.75386pt x 325.2142pt.
! Argument of \@tempf has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.283 ...is \href{http://pkgs.rstudio.com/}{link}}
```

And, here is what the tex file looks like:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{0001-temp_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:unnamed-chunk-1}See this \href{http://pkgs.rstudio.com/}{link}}
\end{figure}
```

I can create the book without the hyperlinks, but I would really like to find a way to include them if possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

As requested, here is the full tex file (its ugly as I am very much a beginner! Sorry about that!):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  openany]{krantz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={My book},
  pdfauthor={no name},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=Maroon,
  filecolor=Maroon,
  citecolor=Blue,
  urlcolor=Blue,
}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.33,0.33,0.33}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.61,0.61,0.61}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.06,0.06,0.06}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.27,0.27,0.27}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.27,0.27,0.27}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.06,0.06,0.06}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.14,0.14,0.14}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.06,0.06,0.06}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.27,0.27,0.27}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.43,0.43,0.43}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.37,0.37,0.37}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\ci}{\perp\!\!\!\perp}
\newcommand{\nci}{\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp}
\usepackage{tabu}
\makeatother
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\textstyleStrongEmphasis[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{uni-titlepage}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{VF}}{\end{VF}}
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}

%\lstset{
%  breaklines=true
%}  
\usepackage{array}
%\newcommand\textstyleStrongEmphasis[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}

\urlstyle{tt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\title{My book}
\author{no name}
\date{2022-05-30}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\newpage

%\maketitle
%\newgeometry{margin=1in}
%\vspace{-1in}
%\begin{center}
%begin{fullsizetitle}
%\hspace*{0.4in}\vspace*{-0.4in}\includegraphics[scale=1]{cover2.pdf}
% The one below almost works
%\hspace*{0.2in}\vspace*{-0.4in}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cover2.pdf}

% This one almost works too
%\includepdf[]{cover2.pdf}
%\end{fullsizetitle}
%\end{center}
%\vspace*{-2cm}\hspace*{-1in}
%\makebox[\paperwidth]{
%        \includegraphics[width=1.3\paperwidth]{cover2.pdf}
%    }
%\restoregeometry

%\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
%\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{center}
%\includegraphics{_book/frontpage.png}
%\end{center}
\let\maketitle\oldmaketitle
%\maketitle 
%\let\maketitle\oldmaketitle
%\maketitle
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-5pt}
 

\frontmatter
%\pagenumbering{roman}

{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
}


\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{plot}\NormalTok{(mtcars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{0001-temp_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:unnamed-chunk-1}See this \href{http://pkgs.rstudio.com/}{link}}
\end{figure}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{plot}\NormalTok{(mtcars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{0001-temp_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:unnamed-chunk-2}See this site \url{http://pkgs.rstudio.com/}}
\end{figure}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{plot}\NormalTok{(mtcars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{0001-temp_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-3-1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:unnamed-chunk-3}link}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
%\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete .tex file?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The problem seems to be caused by `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}` -- using fragile content like a link as argument of a macro is never a good idea. In the specific case you show, you can work around the problem with `\protect\href{http://pkgs.rstudio.com/}{link}`. I'm don't know if this also works in markdown, but maybe try `See this \protect [link](http://pkgs.rstudio.com/)` (There will also be cases in which this breaks, using an url as argument is really not a good idea)

Comment: Although \protect did not work, commenting out that line seems to have solved the problem (hopefully, with no downstream issues)   THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
```

Using fragile content like links, which can have tons of special characters, in the argument of a macro is not a good idea, just don't do this.